# When is acetone not effective when cleaning up residual caulking?

Tags: cleaning, bathtub, caulking

I have read in several places, [including here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87442/correct-order-of-operations-for-caulking-sealing-bathroom-tile/93131#93131), that using acetone as part of  a caulking clean step is useful/effective. I have scrapped off most of the caulk on my bath tub and am trying to clean the residual using some acetone and a brush. However I feel like the acetone (100% according to the bottle) is not actually doing anything. I can't just let it sit there as it evaporates rather quickly.

Are there any logical reason I should not be using acetone to be cleaning up caulk? Is there perhaps a better alternative for residual caulk removal.

Comment: If it's silicone caulk, acetone doesn't actually do much to it. Acrylic caulk is another matter. It's still good for post-removal cleaning unless the substrate is attacked.

Comment: I just found the caulk I used. It was silicone

Comment: Carefully with a single edge razor blade is about as good as you are going to get it.